# Появляется ненужный серый фон

Tags: jquery, javascript, вёрстка

Если открыть этот [сайт](http://andrei.createim.ru/) затем нажать, например, на кнопку проекты (верхнее меню) страница прокрутится вниз. Когда крутим снова наверх, то почему-то произвольными кусками появляется серый фон, который закрывает логотип и верхнее меню.

Answer (score 1):

`background-attachment: fixed;` Зачем? Очевидно же, что нужен `scroll`.

Comment: странно то что на планшете все четко отрабатывает